# Sql Server 2008 Express - Change File-Browser Default Path

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Whenever I open SSMS2008's file browser for loading or saving backups, it always goes to the root folder where the MSSQL application was installed. However, this is no longer where my data is stored, as I've changed the default data and log folders to be on a different data drive on the server.

How can I make this file browser start in the default data location?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a good article on MSSQLTips that describes how to do this.  The link is here:

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1583

Comment: In case the page is lost, it's a regedit in: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\MSSQLServer (Thanks for the link)